# How can I replace text only inside of a specific xml block using sed?

Tags: xml, unix, sed, command-line

There are mutiple port configuration in each XML block in a XML file.

The example below has two port configurations. One in `<Server>`, another in `<Connector>`.

I want to change port in `<Connector>` block only.

In this case, how can I solve this using `sed` command?

(I need a solution which only uses `sed` command because it should be run on any unix env.)

(I want to indicate specific block as name. It is not applicable way to change n-th block for matching `port` text. Because there are more `port` configurations as the comment in a file.)

server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"/>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus  It is reasonable. I will find the way of using python. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not safe at all to replace strings in xml files. You can break syntax, xml structure and it won't permit clever operation like editing properties on node before / after selector and so on...

As @Cyrus suggested : use an xml parser. No matter it is an unix environment. Feel free to make an python or java script or your preferred language for that.